# Access property pf application.properties in outer Spring Boot Java Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot in combination with Angular to write things in a Database. Now I added a Java Project inside the Spring Boot project where are some methods which are called to access a server which has nothing to do with the Spring Boot Project itself.
I have some own properties in my Spring Boot application.properties (in standard-path `src/main/resources`)

```
 prod=
 user=
 password=
```

I want to access those variables inside a Java file which is not part of the Spring Bean itself (so the Java file is not part of a controller or a repository, there are just methods which are called from the Spring Boot part).

I tried the `@Value` annotation but it doesnt work. The `environment.getProperty()` didn't work either.

Are there other ways of just simply accessing a value/property of the application.properties in a normal Java-file which is inside the Spring Boot project but not part of a controller, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application.properties:

```
version=1.0
name=TestApp
date=2016-11-12
```

Read the file:

```
String rootPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
String appConfigPath = rootPath + "application.properties";

Properties appProps = new Properties();
appProps.load(new FileInputStream(appConfigPath));

String appVersion = appProps.getProperty("version");
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare this class as a `@Component` if this solution suits you. That way you can access any bean from the class by using autowiring. For your case:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

String prodPropertyValue = environment.getProperty("prod");
```

But don't forget that if you declare the class as a component then you should not create it as a regular class through 'new' operator - use autowiring for it.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class MailSenderConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender(Environment env) {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol(env.getProperty("mail.protocol"));
        javaMailSender.setHost(env.getProperty("mail.host"));
        javaMailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("mail.port")));

        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

Here is a little example.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException or null with the environment.

Comment: It can happen when you not properly configured your application. Environment may require to use of @PropertySource annotation. Try to found the solution here or on https://www.baeldung.com/. Also, make sure that the instance of the class with Environment field was instanced from ApplicationContext, not just by 'new' operator.

Comment: I added an example to my answer